# Changing the number of decimal places for a specific category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, decimal, categories, hook-woocommerce

I've been trying everything to make a change in my website and I'm not succeeding.

I set up WooCommerce to put 3 decimal places on all my products but right now I have a category called 'gas' that I need to have only 2 decimal places.

This is the code I tried but something is not working (I have very little experience with PHP):

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals', 'custom_price_decimals', 10, 1 );
function custom_price_decimals( $decimals ){
    global $product;
    if( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') ){
       
        if( has_term( 'gas', $product->get_id() ) )
            $decimals = 2;
    }
    return $decimals;
}
```

someone can help me?
Best regards,
João Pedro

Comment: `has_term` takes the post id as third parameter, you are passing it for the second. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/

Comment: And you will probably have to specify `product_cat` for the second parameter, otherwise it will not check the correct taxonomomy to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('wc_get_price_decimals', 'custom_price_decimals', 10, 1);

function custom_price_decimals($decimals) {
    global $product;
    if (is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && has_term('gas', 'product_cat', $product->get_id())) {
        $decimals = 2;
    }
    return $decimals;
}
```